# hardcode username, password in salesforce login screen in iOS application

Tags: salesforce

How to hardcode the username and password in salesforce login screen to bypass it in iOS application. I am using the database.com of salesforce to store some data which will be accessed by different users using their mobile application.

Answer (score 0):

This is really bad idea, the password is likely to change on a regular basis for one thing, and each user should have different credentials for Salesforce as well.

Your best bet is to use oAuth, the users will still have to login occasionally (including the first time they use the app) but after that it will do the login in the background.